# How do i perform conditional check using Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I have a scenario like this.

```
 private val feeder = Array(200, 404).map(e => Map("code" -> e)).random.circular

 private val search = scenario("search")
                          .feed(feeder)
                          .exec(http("search")
                          .get("/search/")
                          .headers(headers)
                          .check( if "${code}".equals(200) jsonPath("$.body").exists else jsonPath("$.exception").exists )
```

Is there a way I can achieve this kinda conditional check. As of now, the observed behavior is, ***"${code}".equals(200)*** will always return false.

Comment: `"${code}"`  creates `String`, which will never be equal to integer. Can you try to replace `"${code}".equals(200)` with `code == 200` ?

Comment: @RandallFlagg I have tried that too. Didnt work either.

Answer (score 2):

You can access a `session` inside `jsonPath` and extract `code` from it manually

```
.check(jsonPath(session => 
      if (session("code").as[Int].equals(200)) "$.body" 
      else "$.exception"
).exists)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/check/#conditional-checking), there is the following construct to achieve this:

```
// with a Gatling EL String condition that resolves a Boolean
.checkIf("#{bool}") {
  jsonPath("$..foo")
}
// with a function
.checkIf(session => session("key").as[String] == "executeCheck") {
  jsonPath("$..foo")
}
```